# Adding Average Line in Plotly Dash Python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a sample code here and need to add the horizontal line here to show the average line. In which part of the code and how can I add the line? Maybe I can add a line chart through trace? However, I couldn't figure it out.

I have a long dataset here, so would appreciate just an example.
Just add.shape as in Plotly doesn't work in Dash.

```
app = JupyterDash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H2("Building Population"),
    html.Div(children='''Refresh for Total Estate Population.'''),
    html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id="Floor",
                options=[{
                    'label': i,
                    'value': i
                } for i in floor_options],
                value='All Floors'),
        ],
        style={'width': '25%',
               'display': 'inline-block'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='funnel-graph'),
])


@app.callback(
    Output('funnel-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('Floor', 'value')])
def update_graph(Floor):
    if Floor == "All Floors":
        df_plot = total_population.copy()
    else:
        df_plot = total_population[total_population['Floor'] == Floor]
    
    trace_desks_popl = go.Bar(
        x=df_plot['Time Slot'],
        y=df_plot['Occupancy x Hour x Floor'],
        name='Desks',
        marker_color = '#26A2ED'
        )

    trace_meeting_popl = go.Bar(
        x=df_plot['Time Slot'],
        y=df_plot['Population x Hour x Floor'],
        name='Meeting Spaces',
        marker_color = '#41C572'
        )

    return {
        'data': [trace_desks_popl, trace_meeting_popl],
        'layout':
        go.Layout(
            title='Total Population: {}'.format(Floor),
            barmode='stack', 
            height=800)
    }
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Screenshot of the dashboard (average line needed)
[image]

Comment: Could you please add a screan shot for your dash to understand more?

Comment: @Hamzah I added the screenshot to the question